# Is there a .NET equivalent of DynamoDBMapper?

Tags: java, c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-net

I'd like to construct a `CreateTableRequest` object from data annotations in a class. It looks like Amazon provides [`DynamoDBMapper`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html) in the Java SDK, which makes this process simple.

How can I do the same in .NET/C#?

```
 AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
 DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);
 CreateTableRequest req = mapper.generateCreateTableRequest(TestClass.class);
 // Table provision throughput is still required since it cannot be specified in your POJO
 req.setProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(5L, 5L));
 // Fire off the CreateTableRequest using the low-level client
 dynamoDBClient.createTable(req);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`generateCreateTableRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/AbstractDynamoDBMapper.html#generateCreateTableRequest-java.lang.Class-) is unique to the Java SDK with no equivalent (yet) for the .NET SDK.

The general .NET equivalent for Java's `DynamoDBMapper` is the `DynamoDBContext` class ([docs 1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetDynamoDBContext.html), [docs 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/TDynamoDBContext.html)). This class provides a high-level .NET [object persistence model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html) that enables you to map your client-side classes to Amazon DynamoDB tables.

However, as per docs:

> The object persistence model **does not provide an API to create, update, or delete tables**. It provides only data operations. You can use only the AWS SDK for .NET low-level API to create, update, and delete tables.

You will have to use the low-level .NET API to create tables.

Comment: Thank you. I feared that'd be the case. It looks like if an attribute is not defined, during insert/update, DynamoDB will auto create it, correct? So, perhaps at minimum I can define the hash and range keys and let app code insert all other attributes.

Comment: @user246392 Sorry, not sure what you mean - you mean if you have fields with no `DynamoDBProperty` annotation? How would the app code 'insert' attributes when you're using a class?

Comment: That's not what I meant. The annotations will be there. During table creation, I want to skip the heavy lifting when I call the low level .NET APIs after I construct a `CreateTableRequest` object. By attribute, I meant `AttributeDefinition`.

Comment: If you have any other questions, please create separate questions to not clutter the comment section 